# How to use Jetty Quickstart in spring-boot?

Tags: spring-boot, jetty

[Jetty](https://eclipse.org/jetty/)'s startup-time can be decreased by using it's ability to [Quickstart](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/quickstart-webapp.html).
I am using spring-boot, in special, my spring-boot project does not use the default Tomcat, but [Jetty](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-jetty-instead-of-tomcat).

How can I use Jetty's Quickstart feature in a spring-boot (using Jetty) project?

Comment: To start with, the project *must* be a webapp (war or expanded directory) for quickstart to apply.  Is yours?

Comment: No it's not (right now), but I can and will change this, if I can use Jetty's Quickstart this way.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to to run my spring-boot application, as a dedicated webapp in a Jetty, which uses Quickstart (all done via docker).
It is not worth it. The described setup is still slower than using embedded-Jetty from within the application (the setup was of course even slower, not using Quickstart).